# Nginx socket io websockets proxy pass

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, proxypass

I've been trying to figure out how to proxy_pass socket io/websocket data in nginx.

I keep getting this error in nginx when the socket io connection is being attempted.

```
2016/02/12 03:57:42 [info] 1047#0: *15 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 192.168.1.1, server: 0.0.0.0:4444
2016/02/12 03:57:42 [info] 1047#0: *13 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 192.168.1.1, server: 0.0.0.0:4444
2016/02/12 03:57:42 [info] 1047#0: *14 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 192.168.1.1, server: 0.0.0.0:4444
2016/02/12 05:11:19 [info] 1047#0: *18 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 192.168.1.1, server: 0.0.0.0:4444
2016/02/12 05:11:19 [info] 1047#0: *20 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 192.168.1.1, server: 0.0.0.0:4444
2016/02/12 05:11:19 [info] 1047#0: *22 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 192.168.1.1, server: 0.0.0.0:4444
2016/02/12 05:11:19 [info] 1047#0: *24 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 192.168.1.1, server: 0.0.0.0:4444
```

Here is my configuration:

```
#inside http block
upstream socket_nodes {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:6969;
    #socket io app is running on port 6969
}
```

My server block

```
server {
    listen       4444;

    server_name  url.com;

    #charset koi8-r;

    location /io/ {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:6969;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_buffer_size 8k;
        proxy_buffers 2048 8k;
    }

    location / {
        root /path/to/my/static/files/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /path/to/http/api/ {
            proxy_pass    http://localhost:2814/;
            #api app location
    }
}
```

In the frontend I get a 404 not found response everytime socket io tries to poll which is not generated by NGINX

My connection string is:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://url.com',{'force new connection': true, path: '/io/socket.io'});
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the server conflicts with the static path file somehow.

I managed to get it to work by putting the application on a subdomain.

Comment: Are you saying that you're having socket.io listen on a separate subdomain?